# can が be used like this？

Tags: particle-は, particle-が, は-and-が

this is a  small conversation
-どこで食べる
-イタリアレストランではどう
my grammer book says that using どう usually opens up a new topic for example about the location
but if i didn't use どう and instead was stating the location rather than discussing it would it go like this？
イタリアレストランにが？

Answer (score 1):

No, it can't. イタリアレストランにが？ doesn't make sense. However you can omit どう like イタリアレストランは?

Comment: thank you for the reply but shouldn't i add a で particle? since its talking about location? イタリアレストランでは？

Comment: You may add で but not adding で would be more common.